# Undefined offset in has_header_image()

Tags: php, wordpress

Creates a function that adds styles to the header.

I get an error message.

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0

```
function my_header_image() {
if ( has_header_image() && !is_single() ):
    $image = wp_get_registered_image_subsizes();

    //var_dump($image);

    $i = 0;
    echo '<style>';
    foreach ($image as $size => $value) {
        if (($size.$value[0] !== 'thumbnail') && ($size.$value[1] !== 'post-thumbnail')) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                echo '.bg-image {background-image: url('.wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_custom_header()->attachment_id, $size.$value[0])[0].');}';
            }
            else {
                echo ' @media screen and (min-width: '.$value['width'].'px) {.bg-image {background-image: url('.wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_custom_header()->attachment_id, $size.$value[0])[0].');} }';
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    echo '</style>';
endif; }

add_action('get_header', 'my_header_image');
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be just `$value[0]` rather than `$size.$value[0]`?

Comment: Then it only returns one image format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data structure returned by `wp_get_registered_image_subsizes`, the array keys are the image-size slugs, e.g.

```
'thumbnail' => 
    array (size=3)
      'width' => int 150
      'height' => int 150
      'crop' => boolean true
  'medium' => 
    array (size=3)
      'width' => int 300
      'height' => int 300
      'crop' => boolean false
  etc...
```

In your foreach loop, `$size` is set to each array item’s key, so rather than using `$size.$value[0]` you can just use `$size` to access the slug.

For example:
`$size.$value[0] !== 'thumbnail'`

should be

`$size !== 'thumbnail'`

and another example:

`wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_custom_header()->attachment_id, $size.$value[0])[0]`

should be

`wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_custom_header()->attachment_id, $size)[0]`

I think that will fix it - hope it helps